# Getting Message "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" while access url through REST in sharepoint 2013 app model

Tags: rest, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am accessing a list through SharePoint 2013 App using REST, below is code snippet:

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: appweburl +
               "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@hostweburl)/Web/lists/getbytitle('SomeListName')/items?" +
               "@hostweburl='" +
               hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
```

when i am debugging it, getting the complete URL from URL tag, but when i am going to access it through browser, it shows me message like "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you".
Why is this so happen while i have the full control over site collection.

Is there any configuration which we have to be made in APP?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Problem solved..!
there is property in Visual studio 2012 app environment.
Steps to Resolve : 
1. Go to AppMenifest.xml.
2. Open it in designer view.
3. Go to Permission Tab.
4. Set Scope as "Site Collection" and Set permission as "Full control".
5. Now access the URL, it will give complete data in XML format.

thanks